# Check if the value is posted and check it's value in single code in php

Tags: php, isset, loopingselector

I have here PHP code that will check if the value is posted and I want to check its value in single line of code.

I have here a single code, I know that this is wrong because I always get the wrong value.

```
if(isset($_POST['handler_name']) == $h_name){

}
```

THANKS!

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['handler_name']) &&  ($_POST['handler_name']== $h_name)){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
if(isset($_POST['handler_name']) && ($_POST['handler_name'] == $h_name)) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset[$_POST['handler_name'])?(if([$_POST['handler_name'])?echo "equal":echo "not equal"):echo "not set";
```

Comment: Mate, it is always good to add an explanation on what the code does. Even more so, when the code is complex.